# node-schedule read the value of a set timer

Tags: node.js

schedule to schedule events.

After setting the timer I want to be able to check afterwards which timervalue was set.

Let´s say I have scheduled my event to 2017-02-15 17:08:35

How can I call my node-schedule timer now to check this value.

I set my timer using this `var j = schedule.scheduleJob(unique_name, date, function() {
});`

I would assume now to do something like this to get the timervalue back.

```
var my_job = schedule.scheduledJobs[unique_name];
my_job.checktimer();
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
  var rand = require('randomstring');    
    var jobId = rand.generate(10); //randomsrting
    var at = new Date();
    var timed = at.setSeconds(at.getSeconds() + Number(5))  //after 5 second     
    schedule.scheduleJob(jobId, new Date(timed),function(){
         schedule.cancelJob(jobId);
         console.log('hi--viral');
     });
```